# DirectX 9 - Getting camera resolutions? (C++)

Tags: c++, camera, directx, directx-9

noob question:
Any examples of how to get parameters from the connected camera, such as supported resolutions?

I'm using DirectX June 2010.
Code to create a device:

```
HWND                    m_hwnd;
HDC                     *phdc;
IDirect3D9              *m_pD3D;
IDirect3DDevice9        *m_pDevice;
IDirect3DSwapChain9     *m_pSwapChain;

HRESULT DrawDevice::CreateDevice(HWND hwnd)
{
    if (m_pDevice)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    // Create the Direct3D object.
    if (m_pD3D == NULL)
    {
        m_pD3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

        if (m_pD3D == NULL)
        {
            return E_FAIL;
        }
    }


    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS pp = { 0 };
    D3DDISPLAYMODE mode = { 0 };

    hr = m_pD3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        &mode
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = m_pD3D->CheckDeviceType(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        mode.Format,
        D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,
        TRUE    // windowed
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    pp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    pp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
    pp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
    pp.Windowed = TRUE;
    pp.hDeviceWindow = hwnd;

    hr = m_pD3D->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        hwnd,
        D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE,
        &pp,
        &m_pDevice
    );

    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    m_hwnd = hwnd;
    m_d3dpp = pp;


    return hr;
}
```

My purpose is to give the user a list of options to choose...

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Well if  you  need  Monitor  resolutions  you  should use  DXUT microsoft  Gui library or QT  or  custom you  should make enumeration  type and declare screen  resolutions.  I  don't know  what  kind of  resolutions you  prefer.

P.S. I am not sure if you will  succeded  with DX SDK 2010 June and if you are  using  latest Windows and  Visual Studio IDE. Simply  that kind of DirectX SDK  doesn't  supported any more by  Microsoft. You should use  Windows  SDK  at least Windows 8.1 version.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't need monitor resolutions, but to get the resolutions the connected camera supports.
I have a well running project with the SDK 2010 on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015.
Just need to figure out how to get parameters from the camera :)

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D is used to render to a monitor, not to capture images from a camera. Depending on what version of the OS you are using, you should take a look at [Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197.aspx) or legacy [DirectShow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454.aspx).

Direct3D 9 itself is also deprecated, as is the legacy DirectX SDK. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/). New projects should use DirectX 11 (or very experienced Direct3D graphics developers looking for high performance on Windows 10 / Xbox One should consider DirectX 12).

For a Win32 desktop application, you should look at this sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CaptureEngineVideoCapture).

For a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, you should look at this sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems like Media  Foundation is not working on Windows 7, and DirectShow is not good enough for me. 
Maybe i'll take a look at DirectX11, but anyway, the same question goes for it too..

Comment: It depends on what aspects of Media Foundation you are using. See [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update/) for details on the DirectX 11.1 Runtime which includes DirectX 11 video and some related Media Foundation changes.